# What does is mean the norm of the differential on a tangent space?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $U \subset M$ open and $f : U \to M$ a $C^1$ diffeomorphism onto its image. Consider $(Df)_x : T_x \to T_{f(x)} M$. Consider a Riemann metric on $M$.

Can someone explain me with more details what does it mean the norm
$$\| Df_x \|?$$

Thank you!

Comment: Pointwise in each tangent space, the matrix norm with respect to the Riemannian metric.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? Thank you!

Comment: A Riemannian metric is a collection of inner products and I don't understand what is a norm with respect to a Riemannian metric.

Comment: let's back up then: do you understand the norm of a matrix with respect to an inner product?

Comment: If $v$ is a vector, then the norm of $v$ with respect to an inner product is $$\| v \| = \sqrt{(v, v)}.$$  If $A$ is a matrix, then the matrix norm of $A$ is $$\| A \| = \underset{v \neq 0}{sup} \frac{\| A(v) \|}{\| v \|}.$$ Am I right?